# How to use "pkg" file setup on Windows

Tags: windows-10

I want to install Anaconda in my laptop. When I downloaded Anaconda setup the file, I got is in "PKG" format. When I am try to use it, Explorer is opening and I'm not able to get setup to start.

Do I have to change the downloaded file to "EXE" format from "PKG" format? Is any other way to install Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't download the Windows version. Please go back to the Anaconda site and make sure you downloaded the Windows version, which, I just checked, comes as an executable (.exe) file.

The MacOS package comes as a .pkg file, so I'm guessing this is the one you downloaded.